# Get difference between 2 dates and show day numbers and dates c# razor mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, razor

I need to be able to get a list of dates between a 'From' and 'To' entered
whilst displaying the day numbers for each. I need to use a for loop so that I can populate radio buttons. Here is the code I have at the moment - but it loops the dates and day numbers which is not what I want:
Dates entered From (01.02.2016) To (02/02/2016) outputs:

- •Day: 1 Date: 01/02/2016
- •Day: 1 Date: 02/02/2016
- •Day: 2 Date: 01/02/2016
- •Day: 2 Date: 02/02/2016

But what i want is:

•Day: 1 Date: 01/02/2016

•Day: 2 Date: 02/02/2016

Here is my code:

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
for (DateTime date = Model.DataModel.DateFrom.Value; date <= Model.DataModel.DateTo; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    dates.Add(date);
}

//Then enter this number of days into the loop to show radiobuttons
for (int i = 1; i <= dates.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (var item in dates)
    {
        <ul>
           <li>Day:  @i.ToString() Date: @item.ToShortDateString()</li>
        </ul>
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need one loop - `for (int i = 1; i <= dates.Count; i++) { <li>Day:  @i.ToString() Date: @dates[i].ToShortDateString()</li> }`. But that code does not belong in a view. Create a view model and populate it in the controller.

Comment: as @StephenMuecke said.

Comment: Oh thanks yeah I know it shouldnt be in a view, Im a newbie to MVC so I am just learning the design pattern at the moment.

Comment: I meant you had the answer right there ! Not that you are a newbie. Everyone have to start somewhere. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options available but you are nearly there with your current code. Just think about it's current behaviour and what it's doing and you'd see your nested loops are causing the issue.

```
 //Then enter this number of days into the loop to show radiobuttons
 <ul>
     @for (int i = 1; i <= dates.Count; i++)
     {

        <li>Day:  @i.ToString() Date: @dates[i-1].ToShortDateString()</li>

     }
 </ul>
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
 //Then enter this number of days into the loop to show radiobuttons
 if(dates.Any())
 {
     var count = 1;
     <ul>
         @foreach (var date in Dates)
         {

            <li>Day:  @count Date: @date.ToShortDateString()</li>
            count++;
         }
    </ul>
 }
 else
 {<p>No dates found</p>}
```

Comment: Cheers! Went with the first option